# Problems with network sharing in Linux - Windows

Tags: linux, file-sharing

I have client PC with openSUSE 12.2 with KDE desktop and Dolphin file manager and server for file sharing with Windows Server 2008 R2. Of course, the first I tried to do is to use Samba and typed into Dolphin:

smb://a.b.c.d/directory

And directory opened with all files. One of the problems is that I need to enter password in every 5 minutes after i close Dolphin. It should remember credentials before i logout. Second problems is that Linux won't open any network files. It must be copied to local directory before it can be opened and it's very big problem because i spend lot of time copying big files that i should only open on network location and run. People said that smb is not optimized for this use and NFS is much better for linux.

So, I installed a Role in Server 2008 called File Services and Services for Network File System in it. And after that, i shared a folder in server (Properties > NFS Sharing) and typed in Dolphin:

nfs://a.b.c.d/directory

And directory opened, but same as in smb, you cannot view or open any network files. Is this problem part of protocol or it is a security issue in Linux?

Please, if you know, help me to find out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to access the files / folders from the MSWindows machine on Linux - in which case you should just mount the remote filesystem on your Linux server.

(Programs compiled with KDEs I/O slaves should be able to access the file directly via SMB - but it's not a clean solution).

You can either mount the shares [automatically](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-a-system-to-automount-a-samba-share-with-etcfstab/) when Linux starts up, or [manually via the shell](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html), or set up [pam to automatically mount](https://www.sit.auckland.ac.nz/How_to_automount_CIFS/NFS_share_on_Linux_upon_logon?) the shares when you login (using the password supplied at login - hence using pam to authenticate against the LDAP origin for MSWindows auth would be a good idea).